# sumproduct vba mismatch

Tags: vba, mismatch, evaluate, sumproduct

I am not sure what is the error to this code, please advise I am trying to retrieve sum value from another sheet

```
For e = 8 To 120

    '''----Item no--------'''
                     
    '''----Branch--------'''



    '''----Trouser--------'''

    Range("C" & e).Value = Round(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(  --('1.Insert_Data'!F:F = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & "),'1.Insert_Data'!E:E)"))
    Range("T" & e).Value = Round(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(  --('1.Insert_Data'!F:F = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & "),('1.Insert_Data'!C:C = ""Branch""),'1.Insert_Data'!I:I)"))
    Range("U" & e).Value = Round(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(  --('1.Insert_Data'!F:F = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & "),'1.Insert_Data'!J:J)"))
    Range("V" & e).Value = Round(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(  --('1.Insert_Data'!F:F = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & "),'1.Insert_Data'!K:K)"))

Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure how to debug this problem. However, having done a lot of VBA myself, i advise you against using the eval function against such complicated formulas. You would be better off looping over the range and multiplying and summing using VBA.

Comment: Is there a `WorksheetFuction.SumProduct()` or only `.Sum()`? If there is, I suggest you use that, otherwise, make the calculations in VBA component by component from memory arrays.  For example: `arrayC = Range("C8").Resize(116,1).Value`

Comment: Range("T" & e).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.sumproduct((Sheets("1.Insert_Data").Range("F:F") = Range("A8")), (Sheets("1.Insert_Data").Range("C:C") = "Branch"), (Sheets("1.Insert_Data").Range("I:I"))) 



--still mismatch

Comment: In your original formula, the condition for Column C returns an array of TRUE and/or FALSE, which need to be coerced into their numerical equivalent, 1 and 0, respectively, using a double negative.  Try `    Range("T" & e).Value = Round(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(  --('1.Insert_Data'!F:F = '2.Counting_sheet'!A" & e & "),--('1.Insert_Data'!C:C = ""Branch""),'1.Insert_Data'!I:I)"))
`.